# Taking input and outputing it Inside of an expansion Panel in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I am trying to take a user input and output that through Material UI expansion panels this is currently what i have to do so. but im getting an error saying this.props.GitInput is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import IdentificationField from './IdentificationField';
import DataGraph from './DataGraph';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class AssociateIdentification extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      GitInput: '',
    };
    this.GitInput = this.GitInput.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.id !== 0) {
      this.GitInput();
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    if (prevState.id !== this.state.id) {
      this.GitInput();
    }
  }
  GitInput() {
    this.props.GitInput(this.state.id);
   }
  render() {  
    return (
       <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleSubmit} />
        {this.state.GitInput}
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default (AssociateIdentification);
```

and I am outputing it like this on a seperate component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { MockGit } from './Constants';
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import GitInput from './AssociateIdentification';

const GitData = () => {
  return (

    <ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
        <Typography> {MockGit} </Typography>
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <ExpansionPanelDetails>
        <Typography>
          {GitInput}
        </Typography>
      </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
  );
};

export default (GitData);
```

I know this is fairly simple but I am struggling to get it to work.